# Как лучше парсить математическое выражение

Tags: парсер, match

Пишу что-то типа калькулятора. Нужно парсить математическое выражение. Хочу сначла токенезировать его, т.е. разбить на операции, операнды, функции, константы и так далее. И потом оперировать уже не со строкой, а со списком токенов. Думал разобрать его регулярками, но я в них совсем не силен(если это окажется лучшем исходом, то разобраться не проблема) и, мне кажется, что тогда придется ужесточать синтаксис. То есть выражение типа `10*15 +19 *sin(90 )` разобрать будет проблематично. Поэтому написал конечный автомат, но по мере расширения возможностей "калькулятора" и там возникает проблема, т.к. слишком много неоднозначностей в синстаксисе и приходится очень много менять в условии изменения состояний.
Очень хочется найти элегантное решение, у которого не будет проблем с расширением и код можно будет нормально читать. Собственно с этим вопросом я и обращаюсь.
Если кому-то будет важно, то пишу на `Java`

Comment: есть генераторы синтаксических анализаторов, например [JLex](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~appel/modern/java/JLex/)

Comment: А какие вы нашли неоднозначности. В приведенном примере все вообще просто. Есть цифры, знаки и буквы. Это 3 разных класса символов, как только класс меняется - началась новая лексема. К цифрам стоит относить точку. Если вы хотите разрешить цифры в именах функций - тогда немного сложнее, если текущий класс "буквы" то цифры так же должны в него попадать пока не встретится "знак". Пробелы в данном примере можно вообще убрать, но если есть пробел - он точно окончание текущей лексемы

Comment: @MikhailVaysman спасибо, гляну, но хотелось бы самому

Comment: @Mike Данный пример относится к тому, что регулярками не удобно парсить(по моему мнению). Выражение может быть сколь угодно сложное и состоять из операций, функций(с разным количеством параметров), математических констант(pi, e), скобок ,в перспективе планируются еще переменые. Поэтому нельзя однозначно определить к какому классу принадлежит лексема, пока не выделишь ее, что сделать тоже не так просто т.к. может не быть разделителей. Собственно в этом и проблема. Пока вижу решение только добавить обязательный разделитель(типа проблема) между лексемами, но делать этого очень не хочу

Comment: Ну смотрите, если конечный автомат: Состояние "начало лексемы" смотрим первый символ, цифра или точка-N, буква-L, символ-S. Если не начало лексемы и класс текущего символа совпадает с текущим состоянием (N,L,S) - лексема продолжается. Если класс отличается - предыдущая лексема закончилась, началась новая соответствующая классу символа. Возможно (если все операции из одного символа) класс S всегда заканчивается как только начался.

Comment: А вот выделение переменных, функций и т.п. это уже уровень синтаксического анализа (кроме случая, если вы решите как во многих языках переменные явно обозначать каким-то ведущим знаком (например $)/

Comment: Кстати, если в именах функций не допустимы цифры. то на лексемы можно разбить простенькой регуляркой `/[0-9.]+|[a-zA-Z]+|[*+()]/` https://regex101.com/r/5R7gSC/1  собственно она делает абсолютно то же, что я написал выше, выделяет лексемы, целиком состоящие из одного класса символов

Comment: Мой [велосипед](https://github.com/vpArth/interpreter.php/blob/master/tests/Interpreter/Language.php) на php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спасибо за комментарии и ответ, они по делу, но вы не поняли сути самой проблемы. Проблема заключалась в том, что мне нужно была максимальная гибкость и возможность расширения текущей версии программы. У меня в планах нечто много более обширное, чем банальный калькулятор. Поэтому мне нужно чтобы парсер был максимально абстрагирован он банальный решений типа *буква - значит это функция*.

---

#### Сделал так:

Процесс перехода от входного выражения в инфиксной форме я разбил на 3 этапа:

- Токенизация
- Трансляция в постфиксную форму (обратную польскую
  нотацию)
- Расчет выражения в постфиксной форме

---

#### Подробно:

- На первом этапе входное выражение разбивается на атомарные части выражения (в моем случае я выделил ***операнды, константы, операторы, функции и скобки***). Для хранения токенов был создан интерфейс "Выражение"(`Expression`), который реализовывали классы, описанные выше. На выходе выражения представляло из себя список токенов, который передается на следующий этап.
- Далее список выражений переводится в постфиксную запись, при помощи [валгоритма Дейкстры](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C#.D0.90.D0.BB.D0.B3.D0.BE.D1.80.D0.B8.D1.82.D0.BC). На этом этапе математические константы заменялись их численным значением. После этого выражение передается в расчетный модуль для вычисления конечного значения.
- На этом этапе, входное выражение, представленное в постфиксной форме, рассчитывалось на стеке при помощи [данного алгоритма](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C#.D0.9E.D0.B1.D1.89.D0.B8.D0.B9_.D0.BF.D0.BE.D1.80.D1.8F.D0.B4.D0.BE.D0.BA). В результате получаем численный ответ.

---

Если кого-нибудь заинтересует, то можете посмотреть реализацию на `Java` в [моем репозитории](https://bitbucket.org/sm4ll_3gg/calculator). Также буду раз, если предложите идеи для дальнейшего развития ;)

Comment: Какая цель данного проекта?

Comment: @hedgehogues пока хочу сделать что-то типа универсального языка для рассчетов, а дальше видно будет

Comment: Интересно как же вы все таки реализовали лексер (токенизация по вашему). Заметьте, я не говорил "буква - значит функция". Разбиение на токены по классам символов это стандартное решение. Хотя оно конечно сложнее чем просто буквы, цифры, знаки, но суть от этого не меняется. Цель этого этапа только выделить токены и выдать подсказки синтаксическому анализу, что это может быть примерно. А синтаксический анализ уже лезет в списки функций, переменных и т.п. что бы понять с чем именно он столкнулся и функция ли это.

Comment: @Mike возможно я вас не правильно понял, но в вашем примере это выглядело примерно так. Основная моя проблема была как раз выделение классов, решил я ее усложнением алгоритма токенизации(можете посмотреть в репе). Но так или иначе это не решает проблему на 100%. Очень хочется придумать простое и универсальное решение. При расширении функционала, сложность которого не будет расти в геометрической прогрессии

Comment: А если при этом нужно максимально гибко - формализуйте какие элементы как выглядят. У меня например был справочник всех возможных токенов в виде регулярки под которую должен попадать первый символ и регулярки которая может захватить весь токен целиком из входного потока. Первая регулярка использовалась для построения таблицы в которой все возможные первые символы указывали на все правила которые могут с них начинаться, это сильно ускоряло процесс, не надо было пробовать все правила. Берем символ и проверяем правила для него. из всех сработавших берем более приоритетное

Comment: @Mike интересное решение, спасибо. Приму к сведению

Comment: Можете еще БНФ посмотреть (https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D0%91%D1%8D%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%81%D0%B0_%E2%80%94_%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0). но описывать язык на нем слишком громоздко. регулярками гораздо короче получилось. хотя в итоге у меня были шаблоны чем то похожие на BNF, по ним синтаксический анализ уже разбирал какие лексемы относятся к данной операции. хотя у вас вариантов пока только 3: операнд-оператор-операнд, оператор-операнд и функция-(-список-)

Comment: Посмотрел ваш код ... Предлагаю уже сейчас задуматься о унарных операторах. разберите выражение `5*-1`. Тут два пути, либо лексер должен умудрится понять что есть значение -1, либо лексер честно выдает `5,*,-,1`, а уже на этапе синтаксического разбора `-` должен быть расценен как унарный (потому что слева нет подходящего операнда). Обратите внимание, приоритеты у бинарного и унарного минуса различны

Answer (score 4):

Немного странно, что Вы не нашли информации по разбору выражений. Есть очень известный алгоритм [Дейкстры или алгоритм сортировочной станции](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8), который решает задачу приведения инфиксной нотации (ту, что приводите Вы) в [обратную польскую запись](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C). Данная запись представляется, так сказать в виде "[стека](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA)" и позволяет легко вычислить выражение. Реализация алгоритма Дейкстры, конечно, не самая приятная. Но, к счастью, есть кучи готовых библиотек. [Например](https://github.com/muratarazgeldiev/Parser).

Если Вы хотите просто вычислить значение выражения, то Вам достаточно в лоб вычислить выражение, записанное в обратной польской записи. Если же хотите сделать это оптимально (быстро), то придётся поизвращаться и построить [дерево разбора](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%B1%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE). Но думаю, что задача стоит именно в вычислении значения выражения.

Примеры обратной польской записи.

Пример 0.

```
Инфиксная форма
Операнд1 Операция Операнд2
Постфиксная форма
Операнд1 Операнд2 Операция
```

Пример 1.

```
Инфиксная форма.
2 + 2
Постфиксная форма.
2 2 +
```

Пример 2.

```
Инфиксная форма.
(2 + 2) * sin(x)
Постфиксная форма.
2 2 + sin(x) *
```

Пример 3.

```
Инфиксная форма.
2 + 2 * sin(x)
Постфиксная форма.
2 2 sin(x) * +
```

Пример 4.

```
Инфиксная форма.
((2 + 2) * sin(x) * 2 + 14) 
Постфиксная форма.
2 2 + sin(x) * 2 * 14 +
```

Таким образом, чтобы вычислить значение выражения, необходимо начать разбить строку на токены, преобразовать её к обратной польской нотации (алгоритм Дейкстры) и вычислить путём добавления в стек всех встречающихся операндов и извлечения двух последних при встрече операции.

```
Выражение:
2 2 + sin(x) * 2 * 14 +
Шаг 0 (Пустой стек).
Стек: 
Шаг 1 (Добавляем операнд).
Стек: 2
Шаг 2 (Добавляем операнд).
Стек: 2 2
Шаг 3 (Встретили операцию. Извлекаем 2 последних операнда и вычисляем их значение, которое добавляем в стек).
Стек: 4
Шаг 4 (Добавляем операнд).
Стек: 4 sin(x)
Шаг 5 (Вычисляем значение. Пусть x == -pi / 2).
Стек: -4
Шаг 6 (Добавляем операнд).
Стек: -4 2
Шаг 7 (Вычисляем значение).
Стек: -8
Шаг 8 (Добавляем операнд).
Стек: -8 14
Шаг 9 (Вычисляем значение).
Стек: 6

Значение выражения: 6
```

Замечу, что нужно быть осторожным с операциями, так как некоторые из них не коммутативны (например, возведение в степень).

Comment: Не `2 2 + sin(x) *`, а `2 2 + x sin *`

Comment: Да, спасибо.  Что-то не подумал про то, что синус -- тоже операция.

Comment: Да не нужна обратная польская запись! Алгоритмом Дейкстры можно и сразу вычисления проводить, и AST строить.

Comment: Лучше бы привели реализацию алгоритма, или хотя бы объяснили его примерно. А то сейчас у вас получился ответ-ссылка.

Comment: @Pavel Mayorov Вы про мой ответ?

Comment: Да, я про него.

Comment: Хорошо. Я вынесу его в ещё один ответ чуть позже

Comment: Я добавлю алгоритм построения ОПЗ и Алгоритм Дейкстры

Comment: И еще добавьте тогда к этому собственно выделение токенов. потому, что у автора вопроса именно с этим возникли трудности, раз он уже хотел пробелы в записи делать обязательными ...

Comment: Спасибо за столь обширный ответ, но я так и делал. Проблема заключалась в другом. Проблему решил, можете почитать в моем ответе.

Comment: Спасибо за ссылку. Долго искал информацию, но не нашёл