# Подсчет арифметических операций из строки без функции eval()

Tags: javascript, jquery

Помогите создать функцию на js для подсчета арифметической операции из строки без eval() или new Function(). Эти функции блокируются Content Security Policy, причем на сторонних пк к которым у меня нет доступа для выяснения всех нюансов. Сама задача: прилетает формула '2+(2+4)/3*2', на выходе должен получить результат 6. В формуле могут быть только одни скобки и сколь угодно операторов (+-*/). Заранее спасибо

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2276021/evaluating-a-string-as-a-mathematical-expression-in-javascript

Comment: [Как лучше парсить математическое выражение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/643449/186999)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Логика:

• Есть отдельная функция, умеющая выполнять операции из строки без скобок: Только умножение, деление, плюс, минус.

    • В цикле находит подстроки вида (число)(умножение|деление)(число);

    • Вызывает мелкую функцию, умеющую делать одну такую операцию;

    • Подменяет подстроку на результат вызова этой функции (число);

    • Когда умножение и деление закончилось, повторяет цикл для плюс-минуса;

• Рекурсивная функция находит все скобки, убирает внешнюю пару, вызывает саму себя для внутренностей скобки. Когда внутри скобки оказывается выражение без скобок, вызывает простую функцию-считалку.

```js
"use strict";

let test0 = '5()(1*2 -3)(-5*-5)1(1)';
let test1 = '4*(1*14.5  - - 4 *-5)*+4/(15/2)';
let test2 = '-1*7 + 15-(-4-4)*(45*6)';
let test3 = '5*5*-5*5*-4/0+2';
let test4 = '-1 +1 -1 +1 -1 +1 -1 + 0 + 0 + 0 - 0';
let test5 = '-2*((15)+(-2*-2)-(-2/(-(2))))';

const applyMath = getMathHandler();

console.log(test0 + ' = ' + applyMath(test0));
console.log(test0 + ' = eval не работает.');
console.log(test1 + ' == ' + applyMath(test1));
console.log(test1 + ' == ' + eval(test1));
console.log(test2 + ' == ' + applyMath(test2));
console.log(test2 + ' == ' + eval(test2));
console.log(test3 + ' == ' + applyMath(test3));
console.log(test3 + ' == ' + eval(test3));
console.log(test4 + ' == ' + applyMath(test4));
console.log(test4 + ' == ' + eval(test4));
console.log(test5 + ' == ' + applyMath(test5));
console.log(test5 + ' == ' + eval(test5));


function getMathHandler() {
  const math = getMathFn();  
  let divByZero = false;

  return applyMath;
  
  /***/

  function applyMath(math_str) {
    divByZero = false;    
    throwUnmatchedScopes(math_str);
    
    math_str = deepRemoveScopes(math_str);    
    math_str = autoCorrect(math_str);

    let result = parseLinearMath(math_str);
    return divByZero ? "Караул, тут делят на ноль!" : result;
  }


  function deepRemoveScopes(str) {    
    str = autoCorrect(str);
    
    let index = str.indexOf("(");
    if( index === -1 ) return parseLinearMath(str);
    
    let scope = "(";
    let open = 1;
    
    for( let i = index + 1; i <= 100000; i++ ) {
      if( i === 100000 ) console.log("Кажется пошел бесконечный цикл");
      
      scope += str[i];
      
      if( str[i] === "(" ) {
        open++;
      } else if( str[i] === ")" ) {
        open--;
      }
      
      if( open === 0 ) {
        // Привет, рекурсия!
        // Показалось проще перезапускать функцию после каждой найденной скобки.
        // При этом учитывая и вложенные скобки scope.slice(1, -1)
        return deepRemoveScopes( str.replace(scope, deepRemoveScopes( scope.slice(1, -1) ) ) );
      }
    }
  }
  
  function parseLinearMath(math_str) { /* уже точно нет скобок */
    math_str = autoCorrect(math_str);
    math_str = mul_div(math_str);
    math_str = plus_minus(math_str);

    return math_str;

    /***/

    function mul_div(math_str) {
      let length = (math_str.match(/\/|\*/g) || []).length;
      if (!length) return math_str;

      for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        math_str = math_str.replace(
          /(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)(\/|\*)(-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)/,
          function(_, a, oper, b) {
            return math(a, oper, b);
          }
        );

        math_str = autoCorrect(math_str);
        // Строка не из миллиона символов, поэтому после каждой операции
        // На всякий случай исправляется всё, что может пойти не так.
        // В основном, "гасятся" знаки вида ++, +-, --
      }

      return math_str;
    }

    function plus_minus(math_str) {
      let length = (math_str.match(/\+|-/g) || []).length;
      if (!length) return math_str;

      for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        math_str = math_str.replace(
          /((?:^-)?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)(\+|-)(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)/,
          function(_, a, oper, b) {
            return math(a, oper, b);
          }
        );

        math_str = autoCorrect(math_str);
      }

      return math_str;
    }
  }

  function autoCorrect(math_str) {
    return (math_str               // Замены:
      .replace(/\s/g, "")          // Удалить все пробелы
      .replace(/\(\)/g, "")        // Убрать пустые скобки
      .replace(/--/g, "+")         // Два минуса подряд → Плюс
      .replace(/(\+\+|\*\*|\/\/)/g, (_, oper) => oper[0])
               // Двойные плюсы, умножения и пр → на один
      .replace(/\+-|-\+/g, "-")    // Плюс после минуса и наоборот → на минус
      .replace(/\)\(/g, ")*(")     // Две скобки подряд → вставить умножение
      .replace(/(\d)\(/g, "$1*(")  // Число и сразу скобка → умножение
      .replace(/\)(\d)/g, ")*$1")  // Скобка и сразу число → умножение
      .replace(/(\/|\*)\+/g, "$1") // *+ или /+ → убрать плюс
    );
  }

  function throwUnmatchedScopes(math_str) {
    let scopes_open = (math_str.match(/\(/g) || []).length;
    let scopes_close = (math_str.match(/\)/g) || []).length;

    if (scopes_open !== scopes_close) {
      throw new Error("Unmatched parenthesis at " + math_str);
    }
  }

  function getMathFn() {
    let local_math = {
      "+": (a, b) => Number(a) + Number(b),
      "-": (a, b) => a - b,
      "*": (a, b) => a * b,
      "/": (a, b) => {
        if( b === "0" ) {
          divByZero = true;
        }
        
        return (a / b);
      },
    };

    return function math(a, operation, b) {
      return local_math[operation](a, b);
    }
  }
}
```

Справки:

• https://regex101.com/ - поможет легче разобраться в регулярках.

• `/(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)(\/|\*)(-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)/`
Здесь написано:

    (Число (целое или с плавающей точкой))

    (деление | или умножение)

    (необязательный минус Число (целое или с плавающей точкой))

`\d` — от слова digit, цифра

`+` — один или несколько раз

`(?:выражение)` — `?:` не группа захвата

`(выражение)?` — `?` совпадаение 0 или 1 раз

• При использовании такого выражения через replace...

```
math_str = math_str.replace(
  /(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)(\/|\*)(-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)/,
  function(_, a, oper, b) {
    return math(a, oper, b);
  }
);
```

Внутри функции можно отдельно получить в виде параметров все группы захвата (совпадения из отдельных скобок). Первый `_` неиспользованный параметр функции: Совпадение целиком.

Comment: отличный, обстоятельный ответ! Надеюсь  люди оценят его по достоинству (+)

Comment: Спасибо большое. Не хватает репутации поставить вам +