# Как сделать число 100 из любого другого шестизначного числа

Tags: javascript

Подскажите пожалуйста как построить алгоритм работы над шестизначным числом так, что бы узнать можно ли путем математических манипуляций, из цифр которых оно состоит получить **100**?
**Пример:

050500 ---> (0 + 50 + 50 + 0) == 100 

595545 ---> (5 + ((9 * 5) + (5 + 45))) = 100 

093342 ---> (0 + ((9 / (3 / 34)) - 2)) = 100 

231357 ---> (2 - (3 * (((1 / 3) - 5) * 7))) = 100 

...**

я нашел статью на Хабр (https://habr.com/ru/post/339654/) в которой приводился аналогичный пример.

Привести 6-значное число к массиву из цифр не проблема.
**Например: a = 123456;

тогда  *String(a).split('').map(e => +e)* // output ---> [1,2,3,4,5,6]**

А вот как дальше расставлять символы (+, -, /, *) и правильно расставить скобки, я хоть убейте не могу придумать :( Бьюсь над этой задачей уже месяц. Хотел сделать так как описано в статье с Хабр (см выше), но не могу понять как в java script это реализовать? И можно ли вообще в JS создавать подобные "динамические" формулы или за ранее нужно прописывать шаблоны под действия, а уже в них подставлять цифры???

Задайте пожалуйста хоть направление в котором думать.

Comment: В статье приведен полный алгоритм решения, в чем трудность?

Comment: а вопрос в моем описании выше: - я не понимаю как можно его реализовать, так как совсем новичок в JS

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```js
//let num = '093342'.split('');
let num = prompt().replace(/(\D*)/g,'').split('').slice(0, 6);;
console.log(num.join(""));
let e = [];

for (let i = 0; i < Math.pow(2, num.length - 1); i++) {
  let part = i.toString(2)
    .padStart(num.length-1, '0')
    .split('')
    .reduce((s, v, i, a) => {
      return +v ? `${ s }${ num [ i+1 ]}` :
        `${ s }|${ num [ i+1 ]}`;
    }, num[0]).replace (/(\D|^)0*(\d)/g,'$1$2').split('|');
  let ao = co(part.length-1);
  for (let i = 0; i < Math.pow(4, part.length - 1); i++) {
    let mask = i.toString(4).padStart(part.length - 1, '0').split('');
    ao.forEach(order => {
      let math = or(order.slice(), part.slice(), mask.slice());
      if(100==eval (`(function(){return ${ math }})()`)&& !e.find((s)=>{return s==math})){
        e.push(math);
        document.writeln (`${math} = 100<br/>`);
      }
    });
  }
}
console.log(`найдено ${e.length} вариантов`); 
 
function or(order, nums, funcs){
  order.reduce((s, v, i, a) => {
        let br = (i == a.length-1)?false:true; 
        nums[v] = op(nums[v], nums[v+1], funcs[v], br);
        nums.splice(v+1, 1);
        funcs.splice(v,1);
        for(let iii = i; iii<a.length; iii++){if(a[iii]>v)a[iii]--;}
  },"")
  return nums[0];
}

function op(a,b,o,p){
  let r = "";
  switch(o){
    case "0":
      r = `${a}+${b}`;
      break;
    case "1":
      r = `${a}-${b}`;
      break;
    case "2":
      r = `${a}*${b}`;
      break;
    case "3":
      r = `${a}/${b}`;
      break;
  }
  
  return (p?`(${r})`:`${r}`);
}

function co(l) {
  if (l <= 1) return [];
  let os = [];

  let oo = [];
  while (l) {
    l--;
    oo.push(l);
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < fc(oo.length); i++) {
    let o = oo.slice();
    os[i] = [];
    let ii = i;
    while (o.length) {
      let ff = fc(o.length-1);
      let ix = Math.floor(ii / ff );
      ii -= ix*ff;
      os[i].push(o.splice(ix, 1)[0]);
    }
  }
  return os;
}

function fc(x) {
  let r = 1;
  for (let i = 1; i <= x; ++i) {
    r *= i;
  }
  return r;
}
```

Теперь визуально идентичные решения с разными порядками выполнения исключаются

Comment: некоторые более одного раза считает

Comment: Ну вот я написал "123456" и получил два повторения)

Comment: например ((8-9)+(9*89))/8 = 100
((8-9)+(9*89))/8 = 100 порядок выполнения действий разный 1,3,2,4 и 3,1,2,4 но внешне схоже

Comment: для 123456 последовательность выполнения действий 53241, 32541 и 35241 будут выглядеть одинаково

Comment: @IvaMuxa - спасибо большое за ваш ответ! Единственное что только я не понял как в примере: ((8-9)+(9*89))/8 = 100 ((8-9)+(9*89))/8 = 100  порядок выполнения может быть 3,1,2,4 - это получается, что сложение выполняется первым? Или может я что-то не так понял уточните пожалуйста

Comment: если действия пронумеровать слева направо то вычитание - первое, сложение - второе, умножение - третье и деление четвёртое. скобки позволяют выполнять их не по порядку а сначала 3 потом 1 потом 2 и в конце 4: ((8-9)+(9*89))/8 = 100

Comment: @IvaMuxa, благодарю Вас, теперь все стало на свои места. Считаю ваш ответ пример самым приемлемым.

Answer (score 8):

Пример без скобок.

```
     let num = '231357'. split ('');
     let opr = ['*','+','/','-'];
     for(let i = 0 ; i < 32 ; i ++ ){
         let part = i . toString ( 2 )
         . padStart ( 5 , '0')
         . split ('')
         . reduce (( s , v , i , a , j = ++ i )=>{ 
             return + v ? `${ s }${ num [ j ]}` 
                 : `${ s }λ${ num [ j ]}`;
         }, num [ 0 ])
         . replace (/(\D|^)0*(\d)/g,'$1$2');
         for(let i = 0 ; i < Math . pow ( 4 , part . split (/\D/). length - 1 ) ; i ++ ){
             let mask = i . toString ( 4 ). padStart ( 5 ,'0');
             let math = part 
             . replace ('λ', opr [ mask [ 4 ]])
             . replace ('λ', opr [ mask [ 3 ]])
             . replace ('λ', opr [ mask [ 2 ]])
             . replace ('λ', opr [ mask [ 1 ]])
             . replace ('λ', opr [ mask [ 0 ]])
             let result = eval (`(function(){return ${ math }})()`);
             if( result === 100 ){
                 console .  log ('%s === %s', math , result );
             }
         }
     }
```

Код запускается но не во всех браузерах, получаю две ошибки:

```
EvalError:<br/> "call to eval() blocked by CSP"
```

и

```
(function(){return 0*0*0*0*00})() SyntaxError: Octal literals are not allowed in strict mode.
```

Подскажите, что с этим можно сделать, и что я делаю не так?

---

Касательно второй:

```
. replace (/(\D|^)0*(\d)/,'$1$2');
```

Тут ошибка была.
Эта часть заменяет "073" на "73", т.к. 073 === 59. В "use strict" такая восьмеричная запись числа - ошибка. Без 'g' флага заменялось только первое совпадение. Наглядная польза от strict, без него ошибок нет, а результаты неверные =)

Comment: А пояснить алгоритм можно на пальцах? Для совсем тупых))

Comment: @lijil , благодарю, что нашли время это все описать! Буду разбираться, так как есть в выражении операторы, которыми я ранее никогда не пользовался и даже не знаю их назначения. Буду разбираться

Comment: как же глаза болят

Comment: @lijil Если очень хочется исправить ошибку eval... https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/987882/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%84%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d1%85-%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%b7-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-eval/987917# - там завалялась считалка без него, но на это страшно смотреть)

Answer (score 2):

```
function makeHudred(n) {
  const variants = [];
  for (let split of makeSplits('' + n)) {
    for (let operations of makeOperations(split)) {
      for (let order of makeOrders(operations)) {
        variants.push(makeExpression(split, operations, order));
      }
    }
  }
  console.log('Variants in array:', variants.length);
  const filteredVariants = [...new Set(variants)]
  console.log('Variants in filtered array:', filteredVariants.length);
  filteredVariants.forEach(variant => check(variant, 100));
}

function makeSplits(str) {
  const res = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < 2 ** (str.length - 1); i++) {
    const mask = i.toString(2).padStart(str.length - 1, '0');
    const maskArr = [...mask];

    const arr = [str[0]];
    for (let i = 0; i < maskArr.length; i++) {
      if (maskArr[i] == 0) {
        arr[arr.length - 1] += str[i + 1];
      } else {
        arr.push(str[i + 1]);
      }
    }
    res.push(arr);
  }
  return res;
}

function makeOperations(split) {
  const len = split.length - 1;
  const res = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < (len ? 4 ** len : 0); i++) {
    const mask = i.toString(4).padStart(len, '0');
    const maskArr = [...mask];
    res.push(maskArr.map(getSymbol));
  }
  return res;

  function getSymbol(n) {
    switch (+n) {
      case 0: return '+';
      case 1: return '-';
      case 2: return '*';
      case 3: return '/';
    }
  }
};

function makeOrders(operation) {
  const len = operation.length;
  const arr = new Array(len).fill(0).map((_, i) => i);
  return permute(arr);
}

function makeExpression(split, operations, order) {
  const splitC = split.slice(),
    operationsC = operations.slice(),
    orderC = order.slice();
  for (let el of new Array(orderC.length).fill(0).map((_, i) => i)) {
    i = orderC.findIndex(n => n === el);
    splitC[i] = `(${splitC[i]}${operationsC[i]}${splitC[i + 1]})`

    splitC.splice(i + 1, 1)
    operationsC.splice(i, 1)
    orderC.splice(i, 1)
  }

  return splitC.pop();
}

function permute(arr) {
  const res = [];

  const permute = (arr, m = []) => {
    if (!arr.length) return res.push(m);
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      const cur = arr.slice();
      const next = cur.splice(i, 1);
      permute(cur.slice(), m.concat(next))
    }
  }

  permute(arr);
  return res;
}

function check(expr, n) {
  const res = eval(expr);
  if (res == n) {
    console.log(`${expr} = ${n}`);
  }
}
```

Мне попалось такое вот решение

Comment: благодарю вас, ваше решение также работает как и представленное выше решение IvaMuxa