# Разбор числа на формулу

Tags: python

Задумался над идеей разбора числа на формулу, из которой, код, должен вывести любое количество подходящих пар чисел

R (вводимое число) = (X * Y) / (X + Y)
X и Y это числа из определенного диапазона, который я предварительно указываю.

Как пример: я ввожу число 150, оно будет равно значениям X = 300 и Y = 300 эту пару и нужно получить в результате (и остальные значения, которые будут давать по формуле 150)
150 = (300 * 300)/(300 + 300)

Не понимаю, как это возможно сделать, ищу помощи.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/643449/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D1%88%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5/643568#643568

Comment: Ничего не понятно. Как превращение текста формулы в интерпретируемый граф вычислений связано с диапазоном чисел ?

Comment: Вот теперь, после Вашей правки все стало понятно :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если речь идёт о целых числах, просто переберите все значения одной из переменных, вычисляя значение второй. Например, для `R=2` можно найти пары `3;6` или `4;4`

(Для эрудиции: `2R` является средним гармоническим `X,Y`)

```
for Y in range:
    X = R * Y / (Y - R)
    if X хорошее
         X, Y вывести 
         break
    if X выходит за диапазон:
         break
```

Пример с выводом всех пар (в т.ч. с отрицательными членами):

```
def pairs(R, lo, hi):
    res = []
    for Y in range(lo, hi):
        if (Y - R):
            X = R * Y // (Y - R)
            if (lo<=X<hi) and (X + Y) and (X * Y) / (X + Y) == R:
                res.append((X, Y))
    return res

print(pairs(6, -24, 25))

[(4, -12), (3, -6), (2, -3), (-3, 2), (-6, 3), (-12, 4), 
 (24, 8), (18, 9), (15, 10), (12, 12), (10, 15), (9, 18), (8, 24)]
```

Comment: В этом и дело, мне не нужны отрицательные числа. По сути, этот код должен показывать пары резисторов, при которых получится указанное число сопротивления. И я не представляю где мне брать резисторы с отрицательным сопротивлением.

Comment: Тогда просто нижний предел (lo) нужно сделать положительным. Кроме того, вероятно, придётся учитывать, что резисторы имеют заданный ряд номиналов.

Comment: Да, есть заданный ряд (просто я не указывал его в коде ниже). Ну и спасибо вам за альтернативный вариант :)

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо тем, кто помогал. Как оказалось формула не работает со значениями, где должен быть знак "+", сделал через перебор имеющихся значений и поставил допуск для получаемых значений.

```
R = int(input("R общ:"))
R1 = int ()
R1 =[""] 
for Y in R1:
    Y = int(Y)
    for X in R1:
        X = int(X)
        K = (Y*X)/(Y+X)
        K = int(K)
        if K-15<= R <= K+15:
            print (K, X, Y)
```

Comment: Этот код не может работать.

Comment: `Как оказалось формула не работает`  - да ну???? См. рабочий код.

Comment: Если у вас есть вопросы по поводу ответа, то спросите там в комментариях. Если это отдельный вопрос, то задавайте его отдельно новым вопросом (:

Comment: @mkkik Может и работает. Единственное что нужно, это заполнить массив своими значениями

Comment: Тогда надо было заполнить массивы тестовыми данными, чтобы код можно было бы запустить. На данный момент запуск кода приведет к ошибке.